# Multi-layer markers for google.maps.api using js (angularJS)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas, markers

I am working on an app which uses a map and I chose google maps for this. This map must contain different types of markers. Each marker has 2 layers, 1 - marker background, 2 - an image which I get from my server.

Best solution I found so far is using canvas to draw an image and then return `canvas.toDataUrl` for marker icon url.

Here is some code:

getting url:

```
function createMarker(width, height, radius) {

    var canvas, context;

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);

    context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,0,1)";

    context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(radius, 0);
    context.lineTo(width - radius, 0);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(width, 0, width, radius);
    context.lineTo(width, height - radius);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(width, height, width - radius, height);
    context.lineTo(radius, height);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(0, height, 0, height - radius);
    context.lineTo(0, radius);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(0, 0, radius, 0);
    context.closePath();


    var img1 = new Image(); img1.src = 'img/pin.png'; img1.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 25, 25);


    };

    var img2 = new Image(); img2.src = 'img/cluster.png';
    img2.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, 25, 25);

    };

    context.fill();
    context.stroke();

    return canvas.toDataURL();

}
```

---

And in the browser I get this:

[Under my map I add canvas witch which url I use for marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7xSk.png)

It looks like the marker ignores canvas images.

What am I doing wrong? Or do you have any better solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem is to create marker inside onload function of image.

---

Example:

```
var canvas, context;

canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = 'img/pin.png';
img1.onload = function () {
context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 25, 25);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {lat: $scope.data[el].latitude, lng: $scope.data[el].longitude},
    icon: {url: canvas.toDataURL(), size: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)}
})
};
```

---